# get an image representation of active windows in cocoa

Tags: cocoa

How can I get a smaller image version of the active windows in cocoa? Just like exposé but I only need a windows.

In exposé you see the running version if it is a movie.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this

[Son of Grab](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SonOfGrab/Introduction/Intro.html)  example